# Two SATA HDDs connected using a Black Duet HDD Docking Station via eSATA to my Laptop, second drive not appearing?

Tags: laptop, external-hard-drive, esata, docking-station

Hi I am using a [BlacX Duet HDD Docking Station](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?C=1346&ID=1895) to connect a [1TB WD Caviar Black SATA HDD (WD10000LSRTL)](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?item=n82e16822136337) and a [HITACHI SATA DESKSTAR (0S00163)](http://www.epinions.com/specs/HITACHI_Deskstar_7K1000_B_HD31000_IDK_7K_0S00163_1TB_7200_RPM_32MB_Cache_SATA_3_0Gb_s_3_5_Interna_Hard_Drive) to my [G51VX (BestBuy)](http://www0.epinions.com/prices/Asus_Laptop_with_Intel_Centrino_2_Processor_Technology_White_Black_G51VX_RX05_PC_Notebook) laptop via the eSATA port.

When I plug in both HDDs in to the Docking Station, connect the docking station to my laptop and start Windows 7 (64-bit Ultimate), only the HDD in the first drive in the port actually shows up in My Computer and Disk Management.

If I swap the drives positions I can get them both to work, but never at the same time.

I also checked in the bios settings on the laptop, under Advanced->IDE Configuration->SATA Operation Mode, and it displays:

> **SATA Operation Mode:** [Enhanced]
>
> **AHCI Port0** [Hard Disk]
>   **Device:** Hard Disk
>   **Vendor:** ST9320421AS
>   **LBA Mode:** Supported
>   **S.M.A.R.T.:** Supported
>
> **AHCI Port5** [Hard Disk]
>   **Device:** Hard Disk
>   **Vendor:** Hitachi HDS721010CLA332
>   **Size:** 100.00 GB
>   **LBA Mode:** Supported
>   **S.M.A.R.T.:** Supported

There should be a third drive, but I'm not certain why it is not being picked up.  Additionally, before I played around with the settings in the IDE configuration, it used to display the DVD as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay figured it out.

My laptop uses a ICH9M-E/M Chipset and this does not have a "port multiplier".  The BlacX Duet HDD Docking Station only supports using both drives when the motherboard/chipset in question contains a "Port Multiplier"

But it's not a total loss.  I can still use both drives using USB at slower speeds, and I can also disconnect them in Windows and reconnect them using the eSATA connection by disconnecting the hardware.